# What would be best security for "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, Schema Compare"

Tags: sql-server, schema-compare

When running "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, Schema Compare" then I would like to run as a user that is unable to change anything.

It looks like the SQL it mostly write is stuff like

```
select
    whatever
from sys.something
```

Is there a group in SQL Server intended for this type of user, or what would be best security for these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the VIEW DEFNINITION permission.  See [Metadata Visibility Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/metadata-visibility-configuration?view=sql-server-ver16).

And note that you can grant this selectively if there are objects in the database you want to exclude from the comparison.